# [JS]Get file names of Apache Directory Listing

Tags: php, javascript, regex, apache2

I am trying to get all the files of an Apache2 Direotry Listing to create AJAX-Requests tp each of them. But I can't find a RegExp to match  in .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dir = 'http://www.example.com/directory';

$data = new DOMDocument();
@$data->loadHTMLFile($dir);
$links = array();
foreach($data->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
{
    $url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if ($url[0] !== '?') // skip column links
    {
        $links[] = $url;
    }
}
print_r($links);
```

Comment: Works, but well it's PHP, but anyways, I'll try to use it.

Comment: You just need to have PHP echo out a JSON string of the links and then you can access it via Javascript to do your AJAX calls. Check out http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Btw a regex would have been more difficult since Apache allows directory indexing to be customized the HTML can differ for different hosts then, also it's a huge performance hog to run regex for something like this. This is faster =o)

Comment: I am trying to do the whole thing in PHP/CSS, not a mix of HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. My code tends to get quite spaghetti-ish in times.

Comment: Not sure how you plan on using CSS without HTML O.o However, you should re-tag this post and update your question then, because you imply you want to use a mix by tagging PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Yeah sure I have to use HTML, but I meant using PHP to generate everything. Is there a possibility to mark Questions as solved?

Comment: the checkbox left of this comment and up